# How to split column into row

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Ex: If i have obj with 6 data length. we know if we loop that's in table row, we will get 6 row and 1 column.

And now I want make that's loop, with my rules, if set 3 rules, so I will get 3 columns and 2 row, or if set 6 then get 6 columns and just 1 row

Hope someone can help

Thanks,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
<table id="tbl" border="1px">
<tr id="tbl_tr"></tr>
</table>

<script>
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
var row=$("#tbl_tr");
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text +="<tr>";
    text += "<td>"+cars[i] + "</td>";
    text +="</tr>";
}
row.html(text);
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement what you are trying to do, you need to implement a splitter logic which is easy to implement. You have to pass how many cells should be in a row if that particular point reached create a new row.

Check the snippet below:

```js
var tblspliter = $('#tblspliter');
var spliterCell = $('#txtspliter');
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];

$('#btnsplit').on('click', function() {

  if (spliterCell.val() !== '') {
    tblspliter.empty(); //refreshing the table  
    let tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
    let tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    let appendedRow = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      if (spliterCell.val() == appendedRow) {
        tbody.append(tr);
        tr = $('<tr></tr>');
        appendedRow = 0;
      }
      tr.append('<td>' + cars[i] + '</td>');
      appendedRow++;
    }
    tbody.append(tr);
    tblspliter.append(tbody);
  } else
    alert('unable to split enter value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="txtspliter">Splitter Cell:</label>
  <input type="number" id="txtspliter">
  <input type="button" value="split" id="btnsplit">
</div>

<table id="tblspliter" border=1>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the content of the looping.

```
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) { // add tr at the start of the row
        text +="<tr>";
    }
    text += "<td>"+cars[i] + "</td>";
    if (i % 3 == 2) { // close tr at the end of the row. 2 is the biggest remainder when divide by 3
        text +="</tr>";
    }
}
```

I use modulo 3 to get 3 columns like you described.